# Incrementing a react state<number> in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am building an electron-react app.

I have a loop iterating over files and copying them into a specific folder using the `fs.copyFile()` asynchronous function. This part works well.

However, now I want my users to know how many files have been copied yet and display it in the app.
I try to do that using a state : `const [nbFilesCopied, setNbFilesCopied] = useState(0);` and I display that in my app.

his is what I tried :

```
  const oldPath = value.path;
  const newPath = path.join(value.dest, value.name);
  fs.copyFile(oldPath, newPath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      setError(error + `Error with file ${value.name}\n`);
    } else {
      setNbFilesCopied(nbFilesCopied + 1);
    }
  });
```

But every thread is increasing `nbFilesCopied` from 0 to 1 and I can't find a way to make them increasing the state.

I also tried to create a function `increaseFilesCopied()` and to call it in the callback but the result is the same.

Comment: "But every thread" you aren't using threads, and even if you were node.js threads don't really have shared memory. Change `setNbFilesCopied(nbFilesCopied + 1);` to `setNbFilesCopied(oldValue => oldValue + 1);`

Comment: @JaredSmith sorry, "thread" was a language abuse. Btw what is javascript doing when managing synchronous functions if not threads

Comment: @JaredSmith and your solution is solving my problem so thanks bu I don't understand why this is working and my solution is not

Comment: You're creating a bunch of closures that close over the *current* value of the state (0) and then set it to that value + 1 (1). So instead of calls like setState(1), setState(2), setState(3) you have *multiple* calls of `setState(1)`, over and over again. The version I posted uses React's mechanism to avoid this, if you pass a *function* to the setter it gets the current state (**not** the value captured in a closure) as an argument.